# How to use flink-fs-azure-hadoop plugin in pyflink 1.17.2?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink, flink-batch

Im trying to use Azure Delta Storage as data destination.

I'm runing the job in my local machine using pycharm, also i installed the plugin flink-fs-azure-hadoop who give me the conection with azure support, just as the [flink documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xffih.png) says, this is my [workaspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTjOE.png).

but when i run my code i geting this exception (full ex):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 72, in \<module\>     kafka_to_delta_lake()   File "test.py", line 65, in kafka_to_delta_lake     table.execute_insert('my_sink').wait()   File "table_result.py", line 76, in wait     get_method(self.\_j_table_result, "await")()   File "java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__     return_value = get_return_value(   File "exceptions.py", line 146, in deco     return f(\*a, \*\*kw)   File "protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value     raise Py4JJavaError( py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o153.await. : java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.awaitInternal(TableResultImpl.java:118)  at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.await(TableResultImpl.java:81)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)  at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish  at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.InsertResultProvider.hasNext(InsertResultProvider.java:85)   at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.InsertResultProvider.isFirstRowReady(InsertResultProvider.java:71)   at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.lambda$awaitInternal$1(TableResultImpl.java:105)     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)    ... 1 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.InsertResultProvider.hasNext(InsertResultProvider.java:83)   ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.  at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:141)  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)   at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$1(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:267)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)   at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1300)    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)  at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)  at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)   at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(AkkaFutureUtils.java:47)   at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:300)  at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:297)  at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:224)    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:221)    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)     at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(AkkaFutureUtils.java:65)     at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:72)    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:288)   at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:288)   at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:288)  at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:622)     at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:24)  at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:23)  at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:536)     at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)     at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)     at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)     at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)   at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)   at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy  at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:139)   at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:83)     at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:258)     at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:249)     at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:242)  at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:748)  at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:725)    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:80)     at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:479)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:309)   at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)  at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:307)    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:222)   at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:84)    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:168)  at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)     at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)  at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)  at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)  at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)  at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)  at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)     at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)  at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:579)     at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)     at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)  at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)     at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)    ... 5 more **Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 'wasb'. The scheme is directly supported by Flink through the following plugin(s): flink-fs-azure-hadoop. Please ensure that each plugin resides within its own subfolder within the plugins directory. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/filesystems/plugins/ for more information. If you want to use a Hadoop file system for that scheme, please add the scheme to the configuration fs.allowed-fallback-filesystems. For a full list of supported file systems, please see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/.**   at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:515)  at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:409)     at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink$BulkFormatBuilder.createBucketWriter(StreamingFileSink.java:430)  at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink$BulkFormatBuilder.createBuckets(StreamingFileSink.java:440)   at org.apache.flink.connector.file.table.stream.AbstractStreamingWriter.initializeState(AbstractStreamingWriter.java:96)    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.table.stream.StreamingFileWriter.initializeState(StreamingFileWriter.java:81)    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamOperatorStateHandler.initializeOperatorState(StreamOperatorStateHandler.java:122)     at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:274)     at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:106)     at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:734)    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100)   at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:709)     at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:675)     at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:952)     at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:921)    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:745)   at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562)     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The important info i think is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 'wasb'. The scheme is directly supported by Flink through the following plugin(s): flink-fs-azure-hadoop. Please ensure that each plugin resides within its own subfolder within the plugins directory. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/filesystems/plugins/ for more information. If you want to use a Hadoop file system for that scheme, please add the scheme to the configuration fs.allowed-fallback-filesystems. For a full list of supported file systems, please see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/.
```

If anyone knows how to solve it I would appreciate it :)

I'm using pyflink v1.17.2, python 8 and windows 11 and i'm trying to connect to a delta storage via wasb.